# Checking if a constraint is satisfied

Tags: swift, autolayout, constraints

I have an `UIStackView` that holds textFields and buttons for a login-page. When a user pulls up the keyboard the bottom constraint of the `UIStackView` follows the keyboard frame.

[image: Large]

For one button ("Try Demo") I want it to be either default height or hidden depending on how much the keyboard is compressing the `UIStackView`. Thus I've placed the two following constraints on the button, with a higher priority assigned to the second one (default height):

[image: Two constraints]

So when the height falls to the 0-constraint, you can see that the button is not completely invisible:

[image: Small]

I'd like to use a method that listens for when the constraint goes to zero, and then respond to it and hide the button completely. I'm connecting the constraint to the viewcontroller as such:

```
@IBOutlet weak var defaultHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint! {
    didSet {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.demoButton.isHidden = !self.defaultHeightConstraint.isActive
        }
    }
}
```

.. but it seems that the constraint is active even if it is deprioritized. Are there any default way of checking if the constraint is satisfied? As `self.defaultHeightConstraint.isSatisfied`? And how do I listen for this event?

EDIT: Actually the `didSet` isn't called, since the constraint doesn't change..

Answer (score 0):

Use a listener for the keyboard, when keyboard isn't hidden you can hide the button and show the button when keyboard is hide.

Comment: That is one way, however I don't want to hide it on each event. If the screen is large enough to satisfy the `defaultHeightConstraint`, then I want it to remain visible.